# Horizontal progress bar with text at progress points

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-progressbar

How can i create a **horizontal progress bar** with **indication text** at the progress point. I want to create a progress bar like this.

[image]

Comment: Draw a text view to the top of the progressbar.Then increase the width of the textview dynamically according to the progress.

Comment: i want that text to be moving with the progress point

Comment: @John did you get a solution to this? An answer would help as I need to implement something similar.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [NumberProgressBar lib](https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar)

[image]

Gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
}
```

Use it in your own code:

```
<com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/number_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

There are [some others too](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Progress.md)